# How to create a border around a board

Tags: c#, unicode, ascii

I am creating the board of a MineSweeper game, and I want the board to have a border. How can I use box drawing characters to implement this?

I am able to draw the board and it displays nicely, but it is without a border. This is the code below:

```
public static void PrintBoard(Game game)
{
    var board = game.GetBoard();
    Console.WriteLine("Contains {0} elements:", board.Length); 
    for (int yIndex = 0; yIndex < game.BoardHeight; yIndex++)
    {
        var line = "";
        for (int xIndex = 0; xIndex < game.BoardWidth; xIndex++)
        {

            line = line + " " + GetSingleState(board[yIndex, xIndex]) + " ";
            if (xIndex < game.BoardWidth - 1)
            {
                line = line + _verticalSeparator;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(line);

        if (yIndex < game.BoardHeight - 1)
        {
            line = "";
            for (int xIndex = 0; xIndex < game.BoardWidth; xIndex++)
            {
                line = line + _horizontalSeparator+ _horizontalSeparator+ _horizontalSeparator;
                if (xIndex < game.BoardWidth - 1)
                {
                    line = line +_centerSeparator;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

My board now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzcd0.jpg

The expected board should look something like this with a border: https://i.stack.imgur.com/87t3c.jpg

Answer (score -1):

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.020;
use utf8;
use Term::ANSIColor qw(color);
my $game = [
    [qw(♔ ♕ ♖ ♗ ♘ ♙)],
    [(' ') x 6],
    [(' ') x 6],
    [(' ') x 6],
    [(' ') x 6],
    [qw(♚ ♛ ♜ ♝ ♞ ♟)],
];
my $blue_circle = color('blue') . '●' . color('reset');
my $game_height = scalar $game->@*;      # 6
my $game_width = scalar $game->[0]->@*;  # 6
my $board_height = $game_height * 2;     # 12
my $board_width = $game_width * 4;       # 24
my $board;
for my $y (0 .. $board_height) {
    $board->[$y] = $y % 2
        ? [
            '|', map {
                (' ', $_, ' ', '|')
            } $game->[($y - 1) / 2]->@*
        ]
        : ['+', qw(- - - +) x $game_width]
}
for my $y (0, $board_height) {
    for my $x (0, $board_width / 2, $board_width) {
        $board->[$y][$x] = $blue_circle;
    }
}
for my $x (0, $board_width) {
    $board->[$board_height / 2][$x] = $blue_circle;
}
for my $row ($board->@*) {
    say join '', $row->@*;
}
```